# Error trying to exclude records with a JOIN to another object

Tags: linq

In my code below, is there any way I can use the results in the object 'WasteRecordsExcluded' to join with searchResults, essentially excluding the WasteId's I don't want.

If I debug to the last line I get the error :

***base {System.SystemException} = {"The query contains references to items defined on a different data context."}***

Or if joining is impossible then i could change bHazardous from TRUE to FALSE and FALSE to TRUE and do some kind of 'NOT IN' comparison.

Going bananas with this one, anyone help? Kind Regards :

```
    var allWaste = _securityRepository.FindAllWaste(userId, SystemType.W);
    var allWasteIndicatorItems = _securityRepository.FindAllWasteIndicatorItems();

    // First get all WASTE RECORDS
    var searchResults = (from s in allWaste
                         join x in allWasteIndicatorItems on s.WasteId equals x.WasteId
                         where (s.Description.Contains(searchText)
                         && s.Site.SiteDescription.EndsWith(searchTextSite)
                         && (s.CollectedDate >= startDate && s.CollectedDate <= endDate))
                         && x.EWC.EndsWith(searchTextEWC)
                         select s).Distinct();

    var results = searchResults;



    if (hazardous != "-1")
    {
        // User has requested to filter on Hazardous or Non Hazardous only rather than Show All
        var WasteRecordsExcluded = (from we in _db.WasteIndicatorItems
        .Join(_db.WasteIndicators, wii => wii.WasteIndicatorId, wi => wi.WasteIndicatorId, (wii, wi) => new { wasteid = wii.WasteId, wasteindicatorid = wii.WasteIndicatorId, hazardtypeid = wi.HazardTypeId })
        .Join(_db.HazardTypes, w => w.hazardtypeid, h => h.HazardTypeId, (w, h) => new { wasteid = w.wasteid, hazardous = h.Hazardous })
        .GroupBy(g => new { g.wasteid, g.hazardous })
        .Where(g => g.Key.hazardous == bHazardous && g.Count() >= 1)
          select we);

        // Now join the 2 object to eliminate all the keys that do not apply
        results = results.Where(n => WasteRecordsExcluded.All(t2 => n.WasteId == t2.Key.wasteid));
    }


    return results;
```

Comment: Where are you creating your DataContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
.....
var results = searchResults.ToList();
.....
.....
.Where(g => g.Key.hazardous == bHazardous && g.Count() >= 1)
      select we).ToList();
.....
```